# Type of Panes in swing in java

Tags: java, swing, panes

What is the use of RootPane, GlassPane,LayeredPane,ContentPane.

Comment: @Paulo: If you ever read this...you should accept the answer below, or is there something wrong with it?

Answer (score 3):

See the link 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html

http://mindprod.com/jgloss/pane.html